# Execute Controller Action From AuthorizationContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the `RequireHttpsAttribute` globally. There is one controller action though that shouldn't use https. Rather than remove the global setting and add RequireHttps everywhere but that action, I decided it might be easier to just exclude it.

So I inherited from `RequireHttpsAttribute` and got this far:

```
public class MyRequireHttpsAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        string action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        if (controller == "Foo" && action == "Bar")
        {
            filterContext.Result = ???;
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can trigger the action manually. I thought using `RedirectToRouteResult` would work, but unfortunately it resulted in a redirect loop.

Comment: in your if condition you want to redirect to some action???

Comment: Yes. Essentially I want to ignore the attribute for that specific controller/action pair

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var controller = filterContext.Controller as FooController;

if(controller != null) {
    filterContext.Result = controller.Bar();
}
else {
    // handle and maybe figure out why its null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to do this:

```
if (controller == "Foo" && action == "Bar")
{
    // Do nothing. This will make execution continue as normal
}
else
{
    base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
}
```